# async.mapLimit usage to make multiple requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

i have such line:

```
async.mapLimit(urls, 10, getCertificatesFromPage, callback)
```

where urls is an array with urls, getCertificatesFromPage :

```
getCertificatesFromPage = (url, callback) ->
  request url, (err, res, html) ->
    $ = cheerio.load(html)
    allRows = $('div.search-result-shop')

    objCollector = []

    allRows.each () ->
      links = $(this).find('a')

      obj =
        companyName: $(this).find('.companyname').text()
        pageDetailsUrl: ''
        link: ''

      for link in links
        extractedLink = link.attribs.href
        if extractedLink.includes('http')
          obj.link = extractedLink
        else
          obj.pageDetailsUrl = nameSpace.pageName + extractedLink
      objCollector.push obj
    return objCollector
```

this doesnt work well because I need to collect all objects from each page 10 by 10 pages, but I am receiving only 50 * 10 links there are much more

what can I do with this code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getCertificatesFromPage = (url, callback) ->
```

You are not calling the `callback` in the `getCertificatesFromPage` function. Without that, the framework cannot know when the work is done.

Comment: can You explain in 2 words how will work callback null, objCollector